# Calculating Excel sheets without opening them (openpyxl or xlwt)

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, openpyxl, pyxll

I made a script that opens a .xls file, writes a few new values in it, then saves the file.

Later, the script opens it again, and wants to find the answers in some cells which contain formulas.

If I call that cell with openpyxl, I get the formula (ie: `"=A1*B1"`).
And if I activate `data_only`, I get nothing.

Is there a way to let Python calculate the .xls file? (or should I try PyXll?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is actually a project that takes Excel formulas and evaluates them using Python:  [Pycel](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel).  <strike>Pycel uses Excel itself (via COM) to extract the formulas, so in your case you would skip that part.</strike>  The project probably has something useful that you can use, but I can't vouch for its maturity or completeness.  [It was not really developed for the general public](https://web.archive.org/web/20210726130300/https://dirkgorissen.com/2011/10/19/pycel-compiling-excel-spreadsheets-to-python-and-making-pretty-pictures/).

There is also a newer project called [Koala](https://github.com/anthill/koala) which builds on both Pycel and OpenPyXL.

Another approach, if you can't use Excel but you *can* calculate the results of the formulas yourself (in your Python code), is to write both the value and the formula into a cell (so that when you read the file, you can just pull the value, and not worry about the formula at all).  As of this writing, I haven't found a way to do it in OpenPyXL, but [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) can do it.  From the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_formula):

> XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the value of a formula and instead stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened. This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in general it works fine with spreadsheet applications. However, applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas, such as Excel Viewer, or some mobile applications will only display the 0 results.
>
> If required, it is also possible to specify the calculated result of the formula using the options value parameter. This is occasionally necessary when working with non-Excel applications that don’t calculate the value of the formula. The calculated value is added at the end of the argument list:
>
> worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=2+2', num_format, 4)

With this approach, when it's time to read the value, you would use OpenPyXL's `data_only` option. (For other people reading this answer: If you use xlrd, then only the value is available anyway.)

Finally, if you *do* have Excel, then perhaps the most straightforward and reliable thing you can do is automate the opening and resaving of your file in Excel (so that it will calculate and write the values of the formulas for you). [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) is an easy way to do this from either Windows or Mac.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Pycel, this looks a bit like the solution I have now.

Comment: The current solution: generate file with openpyxl, then opening the file briefly with win32com in excel, save it, and close the workbook. it's not pretty, but it works. I'm also looking into "spreadscript", a calculating engine. your second suggestion will not work unfortunatly, because the excel sheet is very complex.

Comment: It is worth to mention the current version of pycel does not require Excel anymore to parse xlsx files. Excel-independent parsing works for post-2010 formats though.

Comment: If you go with the open-save-close method keep in mind that you need to have the calculation set to automatic, or otherwise explicitly trigger the calculation

Answer (score 8):

I realize this question is old, but I ran into the same problem and extensive searching didn't produce an answer.

The solution is in fact quite simple so I will post it here for posterity.

Let's assume you have an xlsx file that you have modified with `openpyxl`. As Charlie Clark mentioned `openpyxl` will not calculate the formulas, but if you were to open the file in excel the formulas would be automatically calculated. So all you need to do is open the file and then save it using excel.

To do this you can use the `win32com` module.

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'absolute/path/to/your/file')
# this must be the absolute path (r'C:/abc/def/ghi')
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

That's it. I've seen all these suggestions to use Pycel or Koala, but that seems like a bit of overkill if all you need to do is tell excel to open and save.

Granted this solution is only for windows.

Comment: Well, the whole point of the question, as expressed in the subject line, is to NOT open the file with Excel. Suggestions to use Pycel or Koala are not "overkill"; they are *necessary* to satisfy the requirements. Not only is your solution Windows-specific, it requires Excel. There are folks who use Windows but do not have Excel. Your solution happens to be the one that OP wound up using anyway (see the 2nd comment from OP on my answer, which they posted in 2014), and it is certainly a reasonable choice if you *do* have Excel at your disposal.

Answer (score 7):

The formula module works for me. For detail please refer to https://pypi.org/project/formulas/

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import formulas

#The variable spreadsheet provides the full path with filename to the excel spreadsheet with unevaluated formulae
fpath = path.basename(spreadsheet) 
dirname = path.dirname(spreadsheet)
xl_model = formulas.ExcelModel().loads(fpath).finish()
xl_model.calculate()
xl_model.write(dirpath=dirname)
#Use openpyxl to open the updated excel spreadsheet now
wb = load_workbook(filename=spreadsheet,data_only=True)
ws = wb.active
```

Comment: This will create a new file where formulas are replaced with values. Might be useful but feels a bit ugly.

Comment: well, the opportunity to keep the formulas is there, he just wrote a simple example.

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem, and after some time researching I ended up using pyoo ( https://pypi.org/project/pyoo/ ) which is for openoffice/libreoffice so available in all platforms and is more straightforward since communicates natively and doesn't require to save/close the file . I tried several other libraries but found the following problems

- xlswings: Only works if you have Excel installed and Windows/MacOS so I couldn't evaluate
- koala : Seems that it's broken, after networkx 2.4 update.
- openpyxl: As pointed out by others, it isn't able to calculate formulas so I was looking into combining it with pycel to get values. I didn 't finally tried because I found pyoo . Openpyxl+pycel might not work as of now, since pycel is also relying on networkx library.

Answer (score 2):

xlcalculator can do this job. https://github.com/bradbase/xlcalculator

```
from xlcalculator import ModelCompiler
from xlcalculator import Model
from xlcalculator import Evaluator

filename = r'use_case_01.xlsm'
compiler = ModelCompiler()
new_model = compiler.read_and_parse_archive(filename)
evaluator = Evaluator(new_model)

# First!A2
# value is 0.1
#
# Fourth!A2
# formula is =SUM(First!A2+1)

val1 = evaluator.evaluate('Fourth!A2')
print("value 'evaluated' for Fourth!A2:", val1)

evaluator.set_cell_value('First!A2', 88)
# now First!A2 value is 88
val2 = evaluator.evaluate('Fourth!A2')
print("New value for Fourth!A2 is", val2)
```

Which results in the following output;

```
file_name use_case_01.xlsm ignore_sheets []
value 'evaluated' for Fourth!A2: 1.1
New value for Fourth!A2 is 89
```

Answer (score 1):

No, and in `openpyxl` there will never be. I think there is a Python library that purports to implements an engine for such formualae which you can use.

Comment: That would be ideal, do you know the name of that library?

Comment: Following from the [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issue/251/add-a-value-cache-to-cellcell) there is a library called PyCel. Can't say anything more about it because I've never used it.

Comment: That looks promising, I'll dive into it! thanks! I also found "spreadscript", which runs only on Linux, but looks promising as wel.