# How to get the result of an excel formula in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I need to execute the following excel formula in Python:

```
STDEV.S(A1:A3)
```

Tried this code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.formula import Tokenizer

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A1'] = 10
ws['A2'] = 20
ws['A3'] = 30

ws['B1'] = "=STDEV.S(A1:A3)"

# Calculate the formula
result = ws['B1'].calculate()

print("STDEV.S Result:", result)
```

got the error:

```
'Cell' object has no attribute 'calculate'
```

in this line:

```
result = ws['B1'].calculate()
```

How can I get the result of STDEV.S(A1:A3) then?

Comment: Perhaps `xlWings` or `win32com` to interact with an actual instance of Excel. Openpyxl can write Excel files, but you need an Excel instance to actually calculate their formulas. Or one of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451973/calculating-excel-sheets-without-opening-them-openpyxl-or-xlwt).

Answer (score 1):

In openpyxl, you can't directly calculate the result of a formula using a method like calculate() on a cell. The library is primarily for reading and writing Excel files, and while it does support formulas, it doesn't have a built-in way to evaluate them.

Calculate it manually in Python:

```
import statistics

values = [10, 20, 30]
stdev_result = statistics.stdev(values)

print("STDEV.S Result:", stdev_result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But in this case the calculation would not be done by Excel. I would like it to be executed by excel for different reasons such as 1) I have many other excel formulas that need to execute, not just stdev; 2) Be sure it will return the same result that it would be returned if it was in a regular excel file.

Comment: Everything that can be done in Excel can be accomplished in Python using various libraries. There's no need to use Photoshop for cropping images when there are simpler methods. However, if you really need Excel, for example, for complex formulas, you can use xlwings, but this has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spire.xls for python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/xls-for-python.html) module to calculate formulas.

```
pip install spire.xls
```

Here is an example:

```
from spire.xls import *
from spire.xls.common import *

# Create a Workbook object
workbook = Workbook()

# Get the first worksheet
sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]

# Add numbers to the worksheet
sheet.Range["A1"].NumberValue = 10
sheet.Range["A2"].NumberValue = 20
sheet.Range["A3"].NumberValue = 30

# sheet.Range["B1"].Formula = "=STDEV.S(A1:A3)"

# Calculate the formula
formula = "=STDEV.S(A1:A3)"
result = workbook.CaculateFormulaValue(formula)

# Print the result
print("Formula Result: ", result)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Note: I work for the company that developed this module.

Comment: This is paid from what I could see in the link you provided, right?

Comment: @jkfe It is indeed a paid lib. An extra evaluation sheet will be added to the result file if no license is applied. But for formula calculations, you can utilize it without charges since no file is generated.